# how capture the arguments number need in a function (currying function partial application)

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am working on the **curring function** and partial application,
I am trying to improve the function schonfinkelize:

```
        function schonfinkelize(fn){
            var 
                slice = Array.prototype.slice,
                stored_args = slice.call(arguments, 1);
            return function(){
                var 
                    new_args = slice.call(arguments),
                    args = stored_args.concat(new_args);

                return fn.apply(null, args);
            }
        }
```

This function permit to **pass** as argument a **function** and **a part of the argument** of the function passed as argument (partial application) so the first time you return a function and then when you fire the function again the result.

```
function add(x, y, z){
    return x + y + z;
}

var val = schonfinkelize(add, 1, 2);

console.log( val(3) ) // console output--> 6
```

I want check inside schonfinkelize the number of arguments need to the function "add" (but it should work with every function) so I can choose when return another function or directly the result of the function "add".

bacause if I use schonfinkelize in this way:

```
var val2 = schonfinkelize(add, 1, 2, 3);
console.log( val2 )    // --> function
console.log( val2() )  // --> 6
```

**I have to fire the function two time, instead a want avoid this behavior and define directly the value if the arguments are sufficient**.

---

A possible solution could be the following:

```
        function schonfinkelize(fn){
            var 
                slice = Array.prototype.slice,
                stored_args = slice.call(arguments, 1);


                //* I have added this ********
                if(fn.apply(null, stored_args))
                    return fn.apply(null, stored_args);
                //****************************

            return function(){
                var 
                    new_args = slice.call(arguments),
                    args = stored_args.concat(new_args);

                return fn.apply(null, args);
            }
        }
```

Could be because it returns immediately the result if the **fn.apply(null, stored_args)** return something that is not "null" or "NaN" but I think is not really performant and then I want work with the arguments.

Comment: *If* you can assume that the function passed will only want as many arguments as are defined as parameters, then you can find out how many there are using the `.length` property of the function. So your `add` function will have `add.length; // 3`. So then you can compare that number to the quantity of arguments passed to your returned function.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the property .length because takes the number of all the arguments that are passed, so could be every quantity of number, but if I follow your reasoning, you are right. I have thought also to use also a propriety to attach to scope, like

v.len = 3 (like the response of Speransky Danil)

but I was hoping to find a native propriety of the function, but at this point I think it doesn't exist...

Comment: The native property of the function is what I describe in my comment above. A function has a `.length` property, which describes how many parameters are defined for that function. Yes, a person could add a `.len`, but then why wouldn't that same person simply define the proper number of parameters?

Comment: ...It would be like this at the top of your `schonfinkelize()` function... `if (fn.length - 1 === arguments.length) return fn.apply(this, slice.call(arguments, 1));`

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand properly, you are right!

Comment: Just noticed in my most recent comment, I have the subtraction on the wrong `.length`. You probably caught that, but to be clear, it should be `if (fn.length === arguments.length - 1) {`

Comment: Yes I know ;) I have tested the code.

Comment: If you write your solution below in the "answers" I can accept your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you put in place a requirement that the parameters defined for the function passed reflect the actually number of arguments that are to be ultimately received, you can use the `.length` property of the function to do the comparison of passed arguments to anticipated arguments.

```
function schonfinkelize(fn) {
    if (fn.length === arguments.length - 1)
        return fn.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));

    var 
        slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        stored_args = slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function(){
        var 
            new_args = slice.call(arguments),
            args = stored_args.concat(new_args);

        return fn.apply(null, args);
    }
}
```

---

Side note... you can avoid the `.slice()` if you cache the `fn` in a new variable, and overwrite the first argument with the `this` value, then use `.call.apply()`...

```
    if (fn.length === arguments.length - 1) {
        var func = fn;
        arguments[0] = this;
        return func.call.apply(func, arguments);
    }
```

In *strict mode* browsers you could even avoid having the make the new variable since the parameters are no longer mapped to changes in the `arguments`. But this doesn't work in browsers that don't support *strict mode*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a correct way to determine number of arguments for arbitrary function. I prefer to store `len` in function if it is necessary, and check if it is defined, and if it is and if `fn.len == stored_args.length` then return function that just returns value.

```
function schonfinkelize(fn){
  var 
    slice = Array.prototype.slice,
    stored_args = slice.call(arguments, 1);

  if (fn.len != undefined && fn.len == stored_args.length) {
    var val = fn.apply(null, stored_args);

    return function () {
      return val;
    };
  }

  return function () {
    var 
      new_args = slice.call(arguments),
      args = stored_args.concat(new_args);

    return fn.apply(null, args);
  };
}

var f = function (a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c;
};

f.len = 3;

var g = schonfinkelize(f, 1, 2);
alert(g); // function () { var new_args = slice.call(arguments), args = stored_args.concat(new_args); return fn.apply(null, args); };
alert(g(3)); // 6

var g = schonfinkelize(f, 1, 2, 3);
alert(g); // function () { return val; };
alert(g()); // 6
```

Comment: I thought the same thing but I hoped there was a native propriety to use for discover that number, but seem it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I want propose also a personal evolution of the code but I have to said thanks to squint to has resolved the problem, simply suggest me to use the property **.length**.
The next level it is in my opinion permit to create a partial function able to be called every time you want until you finish to fill all the arguments, I have also simplified the code:

```
        function schonfinkelize(fn, stored_args){
            if(fn.length == stored_args.length)
                return fn.apply(null, stored_args);

            return function(){
                var 
                    new_args = arguments[0],
                    args = stored_args.concat(new_args);

                if(fn.length == args.length)
                    return fn.apply(null, args);

                return schonfinkelize(fn, args);
            }   
        }


        function add(x, y, w, z){
            return x + y + w + z;
        }


        var 
            val  = schonfinkelize(add, [1, 2, 3, 4]),
            val2 = schonfinkelize(add, [1, 2]),
            val3 = schonfinkelize(add, [1]);


        // checking
        console.log(val);           // output --> 10 // called only 1 time
        console.log(val2([3, 4]));  // output --> 10 // called in 2 times

        val3 = val3([2]);
        val3 = val3([3]);
        console.log(val3([4]));     // output --> 10 // called 4 times!
```